# Clarification needed regarding Supremums and Limit points

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

While reading about limit points, I came upon a theorem that states that the supremum of a bounded non-empty set $S$ in $\mathbb{R}$ is a limit point of that set. In the proof, it is used that $\forall \epsilon > 0$, $\exists x_0 \in S$ such that $M-\epsilon < x_0 < M$, where $M = \sup S$. Now, I have a problem in this part. I think it should be $M-\epsilon < x_0 \leq M$ and then, the proof would not hold anymore. (Consider the set $(4,5) \cup \{6\}$ for example). Since I am using a pretty famous book, baby Rudin, it is likely that I am making a mistake. It'd be great if anyone can clarify. Here is a picture of the theorem: [image: Theorem 2.28]

**Sorry for the confusion. I misunderstood the statement. It doesn't say that the supremum is a limit point. Instead, that it's in the closure of the set. Thanks @Bungo for clarification.**

Comment: Which theorem in Rudin?

Comment: Your example seems to break not just the proof, but the statement itself...!

Comment: @GregMartin I'm new to these. It'd be really helpful you could explain a bit. Am I making a mistake? If yes, it'd be great if you pointed out.

Comment: @Cat Chapter 2. Basic topology. Theorem 2.28

Comment: It seems to me that $6$ is not a limit point of the set $(4,5)\cup\{6\}$. Are you sure you're quoting the result correctly? Perhaps there's an additional assumption that the supremum is not an element of the set?

Comment: @GregMartin I've added a picture from the book. Please check out if I'm missing something.

Comment: @SayantanSantra If you read his proof again, you will see that after the first sentence, he is assuming that $\sup(E) \not\in E$, so in fact there must be a point $x \in E$ satisfying $\sup(E) - h < x < \sup(E)$. Otherwise, as he indicates, $\sup(E)-h$ would be an upper bound for $E$. (+1 for recognizing that the mistake was probably yours, not Rudin's :-)

Comment: @SayantanSantra By the way, your paraphrasing of what the theorem says is not correct. The supremum of a bounded nonempty set is in the **closure** of the set. The closure of a set consists of the limit points of the set as well as the isolated points. Isolated points are always elements of the set, whereas limit points may or may not be. In the first sentence of his proof, he handles the possibility that $\sup(E)$ is an isolated point or a limit point that is contained in $E$. The rest of the proof deals with the possibility that $\sup(E)$ is a limit point which is not contained in $E$.

Comment: @Bungo Oh yes. Thank you. I missed that part. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theorem 2.28 and its proof do not state nor imply that $\sup E$ is a limit point of $E.$ It states that if $E$ is closed and if $\sup E$ exists then $\sup E \in E.$ This is done by contradiction: Suppose instead that $E=\bar E,$ and $y=\sup E$ exists but $y\not \in E.$ Then,by def'n of $\sup,$ we have $(y-h,y]\cap E\ne \emptyset$ for all $h>0.$ But (because $y\not \in E$) this implies $(y-h,y)\cap E\ne \emptyset$ for all $h>0,$ implying that $y$ is a limit point of $E,$ and hence $y\in \bar E.$

In summary, $\sup E=y\not \in E=\bar E\implies (y$ is a limit point of $E)\implies y\in \bar E=E\implies y\in E,$ a contradiction.

We can also prove this directly by noting that  for any $F\subset \mathbb R,$ we have (1) if $y=\sup F=\max F$ then by  def'n of $\max$ we have $y\in F\subset \bar F,$ and (2) if $y=\sup F\ne \max F$ then $F\subset (-\infty, \sup F)\implies y\in \bar F$ because $F\cap (y-r,y)\ne \emptyset$ for all $r>0.$